# Cannot trickle ICE server using external IP, Coturn server in Ubuntu

Tags: nat, rfc5766turnserver, coturn, trickle

I have setup Coturn server from Url https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#coturn in **Ubuntu**.

Turnserver is working fine using local-ip, but when I try to trickle using exernal-ip I get error  **Not reachable?**

If I access turnserver from browser url I can access it using external-ip. I get message.

> **TURN Server**
>   *https admin connection*
>
> To use the HTTPS admin connection, you have to set the database table **_admin_user_** with the admin user accounts.

My **turnserver.conf** looks like:

```
user=test:test123    
listening-port=3478     
tls-listening-port=5349

listening-ip=192.168.22.101    
relay-ip=192.168.22.101    
external-ip=202.137.12.10

realm=yourdomain.com    
server-name=yourdomain.com

lt-cred-mech    
userdb=/etc/turnuserdb.conf

cert=/etc/ssl/my-certificate.pem
pkey=/etc/ssl/my-private.key

no-stdout-log
```

I am starting turn server using command:

```
sudo turnserver -a
```

And I try to trickle using below format:

```
turn:202.137.12.10:3478[test:test123]
```

**Trickle**: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what was wrong, it turned out to be that UDP port 3478 was blocked. Also I was able to get trickle if I used TCP protocol (turn:?transport=tcp[username:password])